# A Closed form for the $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(25k^2+25k+4)(n-k+1)^3}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, closed-form

I'm looking for a closed form for this sequence,

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(25k^2+25k+4)(n-k+1)^3} \right)$$

I applied convergence test. The series converges.I want to know if the series is expressed with any mathematical constant. How can we do that?

Answer (score 6):

Proceeding in
my usual naive way,

$\begin{array}\\
S
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(25k^2+25k+4)(n-k+1)^3}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(25k^2+25k+4)(n-k+1)^3} \\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(25k^2+25k+4)(n-k+1)^3} \\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1{(25k^2+25k+4)}\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n-k+1)^3} \\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1{(25k^2+25k+4)}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3} \\
&=\zeta(3)\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1{(25k^2+25k+4)}\\
&=\zeta(3)\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1{(5k+1)(5k+4)}\\
&=\zeta(3)\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac13\left(\frac1{5k+1}-\frac1{5k+4}\right)\\
&=\frac{\zeta(3)}{3}\lim_{m \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{m}\left(\frac1{5k+1}-\frac1{5k+4}\right)\\
&=\frac{\zeta(3)}{15}\lim_{m \to \infty} \left(\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac1{k+1/5}-\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac1{k+4/5}\right)\\
&=-\frac{\zeta(3)}{15}\lim_{m \to \infty} \left(\sum_{k=1}^{m}(\frac1{k}-\frac1{k+1/5})-\sum_{k=1}^{m}(\frac1{k}-\frac1{k+4/5})\right)\\
&=-\frac{\zeta(3)}{15}(\psi(6/5)-\psi(9/5))\\
&=\frac{\zeta(3)}{15}(\psi(9/5)-\psi(6/5))\\
\end{array}
$

where
$\psi(x)$
is the digamma function
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).

Note:
Wolfy says that
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1{(5k+1)(5k+4)}
= \frac{\pi}{15}\sqrt{1 + \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}}  - \frac1{4}
$.

Comment: (+1) Thank you for answer..

Comment: First, there is a typo $\frac{1}{(5k+1)(5k+4)} = \color{red}{\frac13} \left(\frac{1}{5k+1} - \frac{1}{5k+4}\right)$. Second, you can use identities
$$\psi(z+1) = \psi(z) + \frac1z\quad\text{ and }\quad\psi(1-z) - \psi(z) = \pi\cot\pi z$$ to get rid of $\psi$.

Comment: Can we do what Wolfy did?

Comment: @achille hui: Thanks for the catch and the reference to the digamma identity.

Answer (score 3):

Change the order of summation, so it's $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=k}^\infty$.
Then I get
$$ {\frac {\zeta \left( 3 \right)  \left( 4\,\pi\,\cot \left( \pi/5
 \right) -15 \right) }{60}}
$$
You could also write $$\cot(\pi/5) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{20} (5 + \sqrt{5})^{3/2}$$

Comment: I just stopped at the digamma function. Didn't realize it could be turned into a trig function.

Comment: $\cot(\pi/5)=\sqrt{1+2/\sqrt{5}}$ is a little bit simpler.

Comment: That's what Wolfy says too.

Comment: Dear teacher, is it possible to write which method you used?  How do you get the Closed Form..? Thank You.